# Exim - Warning: Sender rate ... / 1h

Tags: centos, exim

I have a server CentOS 5.3 and WHM/cPanel 11.24 installed. In exim log files I noticed these wordings next to most of the emails.

```
Warning: Sender rate (a number, like 2.4) / 1h
```

Do you have any idea what it means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cPanel has a ratelimit option on the `exim` configuration.

Basically it tells you *for each* IP address its send rate.

You can configure a maximum send rate *per IP* *per hour* (after which that IP is temporarily rejected, i.e. with code 4XX) to reduce the server load.

Comment: Is it possible to set ratelimit in exim.conf (I couldn't see that line) or cpanel only lets us to enable/disable this feature?

Comment: @Ergec shure you can, take a look under "Advanced editor". I haven't access to a server at the moment to check where precisely is, but you should easily find it...

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what the name of this option is. Like the O.P., I couldn't find an option that seemed to describe that behaviour.

Comment: @Jeremy Visser Go under `Exim Configuration Editor`, scroll to bottom and click `Advanced Editor`. Then *search* for the line `ratelimit = ...` (Ctrl-F ratelimit should suffice). For the parameters you can put there you should check the exim documentation at http://www.exim.org/docs.html .

Comment: And what does the `2.4` mean?  Does that mean that IP address has attempted to send 2.4 times the limit?